# Can I set a solution-wide macro from VS a project property sheet?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, solution

**Short Version:**

I need to find a way allow a new VS solution to "override" a build macro used by existing C++ projects, but only for that solution, without affecting the value of that macro in older solutions with those projects.   I can change the existing projects however I need.  I can write any new projects (for the new solution) if necessary.  But I need to use one common set of project files to achieve this.  Is this possible

**Long version:**

My old solution of 15 C++ projects directs output to a common folder via one common VS property sheet that they all use.   The sheet builds an output path that's a subfolder of the solution using the `(SolutionDir)`, `$(Configuration)` and `$(PlatformToolset)` macros

[image]

Every C++ project includes this property sheet and is careful not override the "Output Directory" setting.  So all the binaries go to a subfolder of the solution like this

```
\x64\Release\v143
```

Now I have a larger, .NET 6 solution that includes those 15 projects and others.   The solution will have its own output directory and I want *all* output to go there (i.e. no file-copying build steps).  The output path doesn't use the toolset (e.g. "v143") but rather the standard .NET subfolder, like "net6.0-windows".  So the new solution's output subfolder will be

```
\x64\Release\net6.0-windows"
```

I want to find a way to make all those C++ projects send their output to this new subfolder *when they are built as part of this new solution*.  But my restrictions are:

1. I need the old solution (of just the 15 projects) to still work and send its output where it used to.
2. I need to use the same set of .VCXPROJ files between the two solutions (I cannot maintain two sets of 15 project files)
3. I cannot rely on forcing the developer to define some environment variable before opening the solution.

I can make whatever edits I need to the old projects.  But when building with the old solution, the output folder must be the same.

This would be really easy if VS property sheets macros could be "conditional" and would then be the same for all projects in the solution  (like `$(SolutionDir)`).  That is, if I could make my property sheet only define that macro (or some other) *if it was not already defined*.    But I don't see a way to do that

Is what I want possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Well the conditional import of the property sheet that @user7860670 suggeested works fine.  I can verify that.  It makes sense since I now see that Visual Studio does that itself when it creates your default project.  Some of the those Microsoft property sheets already have conditions on their import.  Unfortunately I have been unable to proceed further because at work I keep getting pulled on to other tasks.  Examining the macro list makes it seem like it works but I won't be sure until I have time to make enough changes to do a full build. 
 I will post back here when I am done

Comment: I will add that one great thing about his conditional import approach is that you don't even have to do it in a .VCXPROJ file.  You can add that conditional import directly inside the same property sheet that defines the property potentially being overridden.   Because property sheets already can contain others

Comment: Just thought I'd update that yes it works just as well as expected.  One thing though:  I was wrong about being able to just conditionally add it to the one .props file where the macro it overrides is defined.  That did not appear to work.   I was forced to conditionally add it to every project in every configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While property sheets macros are not conditional, property sheets themselves could be included conditionally. So you can create a solution-level property sheet with custom output directory and then modify all your projects to include this property sheet if it exists:

```
<ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import
        Project="$(SolutionDir)outputdir.props"
        Condition="exists('$(SolutionDir)outputdir.props')"
        Label="Outputdir override" />
</ImportGroup>
```

Comment: This sounds like a very useful approach.  Thank you.   I'll try this tonight when I get home and report back

Comment: OK, finally got a chance to get back to this after being pulled on to many other things.  Works like a champ and is a very elegant solution.  Thank you